# Change color of JComponent after paintComponent has finished

Tags: java, swing, colors, paintcomponent, jcomponent

I am testing one small widget class that extends JComponent
the constructor for the widget contains one vector and sets PreferredSize of the component, then there is the paintComponent:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.drawString("this is text one", 10, 10);
            //here I draw some shapes based on the 
            //vector size and integers
        }
    }
```

the component is drawn correctly and after that i call some other methods in main, when the methods finish their jobs i call **widget.methodsFinished():**

```
methodsFinished(){
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.drawString("this is text two", 30, 30);
                this.update(g);
}
```

I get nullpointer exception by doing this, can you tell me how to correctly update the color of already drawn shapes in this component, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> can you tell me how to correctly update the color of already drawn
>   shapes in this component, thank you in advance.

Not really so tough:

1. Declare a private Color field in your class context.
2. Declare a public `setShapeColor(Color color)` to set the color to the component
3. invoke `repaint()` to reflect the color changes
4. And as a warning: don't forget to call `super.paintComponent(g);` inside the `paitnComponent(Graphics)` function, which you haven't done.

   ```
    class MyComponent extends JPanel
    {
        private Color shapeColor = Color.RED;

        public void setShapeColor(Color color)
        {
          this.shapeColor = color; 
        }

       @Override
      public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
       super.paintComponent(g);
       g.setColor(shapeColor);
       g.drawString("this is text one", 10, 10);
           //here I draw some shapes based on the 
           //vector size and integers
          }
      }
    }
   ```

Though as OOP principle, you should actually declare a `MyShape` class with `Color` attribute and before drawing use the setter method as the example to set the color to the shape.

Comment: thank you, this is close to what i need, and I will test more to adapt it to the requirements